# Getting Springseed error on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apt

```
vinay@vinay-TravelMate-P257-M:~/Documents/projects/westcon/nimbus4/nimbus4-api(QA)$ sudo apt-get install firefox:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libxtst6:i386
[sudo] password for vinay: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 is already the newest version.
libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 is already the newest version.
libxtst6:i386 is already the newest version.
firefox:i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up springseed (2.0) ...
unzip:  cannot find or open Springseed.zip, Springseed.zip.zip or Springseed.zip.ZIP.
dpkg: error processing package springseed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 springseed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Above is the error that I get when try to install any software to Ubuntu using `apt-get`.

Please, help me on this! It has blocked me many times as sometimes the software gets installed properly and other times it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with a previous `apt` command? None of the to install packages has a reference to springseed.

- check `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` for a post install file named `springseed` and 
  remove it.

Your install will then no longer complain about it.

Did you try to install [springseed](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/springseed-2-0-linux-app-released) itself perhaps? If so their package is broken ... edit: [and has been since 2014 it seems](https://github.com/spsdco/notes/issues/173). Filename to remove is `/var/lib/dpkg/info/springseed.postinst` according to the link.

Comment: removing the post install script worked for me and removed the error but why we are removing it?

Comment: The package it comes from is bugged and left that file on your system. It is a post-install file and gets started every time you install something. So removing it is the best method to get rid of it.